# Construct equation of ellipse, if focuses are $F_1 (-1, -1), F_2 (1, 1)$, height (perpendicular to $F_1 F_2$) $b = 1$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

First of all, I know the right answer. It's $2x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2 - 3 = 0$.
What is unknown to me, is how to obtain that answer.
I've tried to make equation like $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$
We know $b$.
$c$ is half-distance between $F_1$ and $F_2$, so $c = \sqrt{2}$  (full distance $ = \sqrt{8} = 2\sqrt{2}$)
According to some formulas, $b = \sqrt{a^2 - c^2}$, hence $a^2 = b^2 + c^2 = 1^2 + (\sqrt{2})^2 = 3$

So equation "should be" the next one: $\frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{y^2}{1} = 1$

But it's a wrong equation. Obviously, this ellipse has been rotated by 45 degrees. Some posts hinted me that I should put $(a_0 x + a_1 y)^2$ in numerator.
Unfortunately, I don't know how to "rotate" ellipse in such form of equation. Perhaps, I need somehow to come up with more generalized form of equation
$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$, but still I don't know to identify the coefficients

Anyway, I would be glad to perceive any help on your behalf.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right answer? From your description, the final equation should be symmetric in $x$ and $x$ because the line $y=x$ is a line of symmetry

Comment: @DavidQuinn sorry, forgot to put $2$ before $x$. Now equation is $2x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2 - 3 = 0$. Is it right now?

Comment: Yes that’s correct now

Comment: By symmetry, the equation must be of the form $x^2+y^2+kxy=d$. Substitute there $y=x$ and $y=-x$ to find the known coordinates of the vertices, and from there compute $k$ and $d$.

Comment: Do you know about rotation matrices?

Comment: @DavidQuinn unfortunately, I don't. But gonna look at it. Thank you!

Comment: Let me know if you need me to post the answer

Comment: @DavidQuinn frankly speaking, I would like you to post the answer. Abstract things are a little bit obscure (especially for nonprofessional mathematicians like me), but in our case answer implies concrete example of using such abstract concepts. Hence, it will be much more useful for gaining knowledge (at least I hope so). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\left(\begin{matrix}X\\Y\end{matrix}\right)$ is the image of the vector $\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)$ after rotation by $45^o$, then $$\left(\begin{matrix}X\\Y\end{matrix}\right)=M\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)$$

Where $$M=\left(\begin{matrix}\cos 45&-\sin 45\\\sin 45&\cos 45\end{matrix}\right)$$
$$\implies \left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)=M^{-1}\left(\begin{matrix}X\\Y\end{matrix}\right)$$
Where $$M^{-1}=\left(\begin{matrix}\cos 45&\sin 45\\-\sin 45&\cos 45\end{matrix}\right)$$
Hence $$\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}X\\Y\end{matrix}\right)$$

So, taking the equation of the ellipse you found, i.e. $x^2+3y^2=3$, substitute into this $$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}X+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}Y$$ and $$y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}X+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}Y$$ and you get the equation of the required rotated ellipse $$2X^2-2XY+2Y^2=3$$